# как изменить код что бы загружать свой датасет и сделать импорт изображения а не вставлять его ссылку

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, классификация

Я новичок в изучение Tensorflow и не могу понять как изменить этот код что бы загружать свой датасет и сделать импорт изображения а не вставлять его ссылкой на изображение
Делаю на google colab

````
import numpy as np
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf


from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential```

**загрузка датасета**
import pathlib

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
dataset_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos.tar', origin=dataset_url, extract=True)
dataset_dir = pathlib.Path(dataset_dir).with_suffix('')

image_count = len(list(dataset_dir.glob("*/*.jpg")))
print(f"Всего изображений: {image_count}")

batch_size = 32
img_width = 180
img_height = 180

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    dataset_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    dataset_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(f"Class names: {class_names}")

# cache
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

# create model
num_classes = len(class_names)
model = Sequential([
    # т.к. у нас версия TF 2.6 локально
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),

    # дальше везде одинаково
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),

    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),

    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),

    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

# compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'])

# print model summary
model.summary()

# train the model
epochs = 10 # количество эпох тренировки
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs)

# visualize training and validation results
acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs_range = range(epochs)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()

model = Sequential([

    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),


    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal", input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomContrast(0.2),


    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),

    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),

    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),


    layers.Dropout(0.2),

    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

# compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'])

# print model summary
model.summary()

# train the model
epochs = 20 # количество эпох тренировки
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs)

# visualize training and validation results
acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs_range = range(epochs)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()

**#Вот тут я закидываю ссылку на изображение из инета и его название а как сделать просто выбор сайта с компьютера или гугл диска**
# load image
sunflower_url = "https://dachadacha.com/templates/yootheme/cache/kunfu-2ceb1d29.jpeg"
sunflower_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('kunfu-2ceb1d29', origin=sunflower_url)

img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
    sunflower_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
)
img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)

# make predictions
predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

# print inference result
print("На изображении скорее всего {} ({:.2f}% вероятность)".format(
    class_names[np.argmax(score)],
    100 * np.max(score)))

# show the image itself
img.show()

from google.colab import files

model_file_name = "my_flowers_model.h5"

# save model
model.save(model_file_name)

# download model
files.download(model_file_name)```
````